# Finding minimum value from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I was having some problem when trying to find the minimum distance from an array. I got a list of distance retrieved from Servlet and I loop through it to find the minimum. Here is the code:

```
function getAllTaxiLoc(){
var taxiIcon = [];  
var minDist = 0;
var minDistPlate = "";
$.ajax({
    url: "/TrackNYP/TrackNYPServlet?action=GetAllTaxiLoc",
    type: "GET",
    data: "",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, jsondata) {
            var taxiPlate = jsondata.taxiPlate;
            var taxiLocX = jsondata.taxiLocX;
            var taxiLocY = jsondata.taxiLocY;

            // Calculating to determine if the taxi location is within buffer radius
            var xs = 0;
            var ys = 0;
            xs = taxiLocX - 29770.742075;
            xs = xs * xs; 
            ys = taxiLocY - 40062.99945;
            ys = ys * ys;
            var distance = Math.sqrt( xs + ys );

            if(distance < 800){
            //Plot marker onto map
                if(minDist > distance){
                    minDist = distance;
                    minDistPlate = taxiPlate;
                }
            }

            console.log(minDist + "DIST");
            console.log(minDistPlate + "PLATE");
        });
    },
    error: function (request, state, errors) {
    }
});
}
```

From these code, the minDist and minDistPlate I printed out was 0 and empty. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: it means the code for your input did not enter the condition if(distance < 800 )

Comment: @MightyPork made a mistake in haste :)

Comment: Nope, it did. Because the markers are plotted onto the map. Just that it could not get the minimum. Is it because somewhere in my logic were wrong?

Comment: Log your distances before the if statement and see what values you are getting.

Comment: Are you saying that xs+ys > 640000?

Comment: Down voter mind to explain?

Comment: Not my downvote, but if my answer solved your problem, you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set `minDist = 0` in the start of your code. 0 will always be the minimum distance if you are comparing it to actual distances. In other words, `if(minDist > distance)` will never return true. You need to set `minDist = 999999` or some number larger than you expect the minimum distance to be.